# El arreglo json no me devuelve los datos

Tags: php, json, sql

El problema que tengo se basa en que desde un archivo php intento hacer una consulta a la base de datos, pero la consulta no me devuelve nada ya que los valores que trae muchos son en español, o sea tienen caracteres especiales como: acentos, ñ y así. Y muchos dirán que si me devuelve algún error, pues no, la consulta se ejecuta correctamente y no me pinta los datos en un arreglo json, solo si hago un var_dump.

Comment: ¿Las base de datos es mysql? ¿Qué codificación de caracteres estás usando? Por favor, muéstranos tu código PHP para ver qué puede estar fallando

Comment: Gracias por responder, luego de buscar una solución encontré una la cual me sirvió.
Lo que sucede era mi archivo de conexión, donde yo le paso la consulta para que la ejecute antes de esa ejecución agregue la siguiente linea de código: **parent::exec("set names utf8");** y así me funciono.